# Auto rename files through excel sheet or through folder of these files

Tags: microsoft-excel, batch, rename

I have excel sheets with lot of files names like..
I want to renames all files through excel sheet and renames files itself..
Or 2nd condition is , if i rename files my self and rename in excel sheet as well..
thanks..
waiting the easiest way...

Comment: Please provide an example of which files are to be included in the Excel spreadsheet as well as how the spreadsheet is structured (i.e. which columns contain which information).

Comment: Please clarify your question. You want files to be named through an index on an excel sheet? Or you want excel sheets to be indexed through a named file? What are you trying to accomplish?